# get parameter modifier reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have a *SimplePojo* class and I would like to retrieve parameter modifier at *run-time* using **reflection**.

However, it does not seem to work ... SSCEE

```
public final class SimplePojo {

    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    public SimplePojo(String name, final int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {

    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

And this is how I try to check if parameter modifier is **FINAL**

```
for (Class<?> paramClazz : method.getParameterTypes()) {
            if (!Modifier.isFinal(paramClazz.getModifiers())) {
                throw new ConstraintViolationException(
                        String.format("Parameters of method '%s' in '%s' must be declared as 'final'",
                                method.getName(),
                                point.getTarget().getClass().getCanonicalName()
                        )
                );
            }
        }
```

EDIT:

```
//are all constructors params final
        for (Constructor constructor : clazz.getConstructors()) {
            for (Class<?> constructorParam : constructor.getParameterTypes()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "constructorParam:" + constructorParam.getName() + ", mod: " + constructorParam.getModifiers());
                if (!Modifier.isFinal(constructorParam.getModifiers())) {
                    throw new ConstraintViolationException(
                            String.format("Constructor parameters in '%s' annotated with '%s'" +
                                            " must be declared as 'final'",
                                    clazz.getCanonicalName(),
                                    Inmutable.class.getSimpleName()
                            )
                    );
                }
            }
        }
```

and output:

```
constructorParam:java.lang.String, mod: 17
constructorParam:int, mod: 1041
```

Comment: That's because `paramClazz.getModifiers()` is returning the modifiers *of the class*, not of its use as a parameter.

Comment: @AndyTurner I don't think so ... I've edit the code as you can see modifiers values are different.

Comment: It is definitely so. `Class` instances are singleton (per class loader), so `Class.getModifiers()` must always return the same value - they don't depend upon the context in which the class is used, since the `Class` instance has no way of knowing that.

Comment: @AndyTurner okey sorry, my bad ... so afaik, theres no way to achieve this ? :) I know that it is possible at Java 8 :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Java 8, you can use the [`Executable.getParameters()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Executable.html#getParameters--) method to get the formal parameters of a `Method`.

This returns an array of `Parameter` instances, on which you can invoke [`Parameter.getModifiers()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Parameter.html#getModifiers--).

I don't believe there is a standard pre-Java 8 solution.

Comment: Indeed - and further, this "names" part will only work with the correct [compiler flag](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html) and at the cost of bytecode size.

Answer (score -2):

[getModifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Parameter.html#getModifiers--) returns a set of flags.

Try this:

```
final int FINAL = 0x0010;

if (!(paramClazz.getModifiers() & FINAL)) {
   throw new ...
```

Comment: From the [JavaDoc for `Modifier.isFinal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html#isFinal(int)) "_Return true if the integer argument includes the final modifier, false otherwise._" The OP's code is (much more) correct (than this).